# Google Analytics: UniqueEvents affected by different EventValues?

Tags: google-analytics

Does `UniqueEvent` also consider the `EventValue` field?

Let's make an example.
In the same user session, these two analytics are sent:

1)
`EventCategory = "UI"
EventAction = "Click"
EventLabel = "Result"
EventValue = 5`

2)
`EventCategory = "UI"
EventAction = "Click"
EventLabel = "Result"
EventValue = 3`

do they count for 1 or 2 `UniqueEvent`?

I have been assuming so far that `EventValue` is irrelevant for the UniqueEvent, and it could even be used for sending the current timestamp.

Comment: "Unique events are incremented by unique actions. Any time a user interacts with an object tagged with a particular action name, the initial interaction is logged as one unique event for that action name. Any additional interaction with the same action trigger for that user's session will not contribute to the unique event calculation for that particular action. This is true even if the user leaves that object and begins to interact with another object tagged via the same action name." (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en). Also this is off topic.

Comment: Funnily enough the tooltip on unique events contradicts the documentation as it reads "The number of unique events per category, action, or label."

Answer (score 1):

The Unique Event definition is:

> Unique Events: The number of times during a date range that a session
>   contained the specific dimension or combination of dimensions.

One important thing to notice is that Unique Events has nothing to do with Events. If this sounds confusing is because it is, but stay with me.

Unique Events is a special metric in Google Analytics it is context dependent. The number of unique events will depend on the dimension, or combination of dimensions you use.

Want proof that unique events has nothing to do with events? Go to an account with a bunch of pageviews and 0 events, and try to create a report of any dimension by page, the number you see should be close to unique pageviews (but not quite).

Event Value is a metric not a dimension, so it can never influence unique events.

Now to your question on whether your example counts as 1 or 2 unique events, the answer is not defined unless you define the actual report you are trying to do.

Comment: I admit I do not understand your proof, plus this seems to be flat-out contradicted by the documentation and the tooltip on the "Unique Events" metric (which in turn contradicts the documentation).  I cannot even find a canonical source for the definition you gave (searching the exact phrase returns 2 SO answers and an article on analyticsedge, but nothing from Google). Do you have by chance a link for us ?